# "tns run ios --emulator" is throwing error "Command failed: /bin/sh -c ruby -e "require 'xcodeproj';"

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nativescript

This is in Mac and I am an absolute newbie.I am following Nativescript course in Pluralsight to get upto speed with App Development. I have installed all the pre-requisites (Xcode, nativescript, typescript etc.) as prescribed in the course.

I have created a very simple nativescript project with a button in the xml page.  However when i run the command "tns run ios --emulator" in the terminal, I get the error

Command failed: /bin/sh -c ruby -e "require 'xcodeproj'; Xcodeproj::Config.new('/Users/username/rps-conf/platforms/ios/plugins-debug.xcconfig').merge(Xcodeproj::Config.new('/Users/username/rps-conf/app/App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfig')).save_as(Pathname.new('/Users/username/rps-conf/platforms/ios/plugins-debug.xcconfig'))"
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError)
    from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from -e:1:in `'

I have a programming background (.Net) so I would like to understand what exactly is the problem rather than blindly trying out the automated instructions given in the terminal('try gem pristine etc.')

Comment: did You try gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2 as in your descrpition?

Comment: Do you have CocoaPods installed (pod--version) - https://cocoapods.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check NativeScript installition is it correct... try `tns doctor` if its ok

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by uninstalling node and ruby and re-installing everything manually as per the advanced setup instructions found here : docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x